# How to open WUBI disk files in Windows?

Tags: wubi

I have an Ubuntu MATE 20.04 installation made using WUBI, i want to access the Ubuntu files from Windows 7, i tried using Ext2explore and Explore2fs, none worked, Ext2explore showed the files and folders at the root of the drive, but nothing appeared inside the folders/files, Explore2fs didn't show anything

Comment: This community stopped supporting WUBI-based installations when 12.04 reached End Of Life in 2017. Sorry.

Comment: Windows drivers that allow you to read/write to ext2/3/4 partitions **WILL** corrupt your Linux partitions. Create a new NTFS partition to share files between Windows and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Try [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/). It supports reading of disk images which contain ext4 file system.